# "Best of Stack Exchange" posts

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

It would be awesome if we could have a "best of" site for posts from across the SE network, or a [best-of-so](/questions/tagged/best-of-so) (or other site name) tag for each site. It would get updated daily, weekly or monthly, perhaps by moderators, with questions from each site that are interesting or educational.

Comment: Best of Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/52443

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually "best of" is determined by the voting on a question.

If you're interested in a particular topic, you could either search or filter by tag, then sort the results in descending order by the vote count.

Answer (score 2):

- [Best of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/stats/answers?anpage=1&ansort=votes&userid=22656)
- [Best of Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=always-friday-in-iceland&sort=votes&pagesize=50)